# Why does logstash parse this user agent as IE7

Tags: logstash, user-agent

I have the following user agent:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
```

Which is being sent to logstash and user-agent plugin parses it as IE7. To be specific, like that:

```
{
  "name" : "IE",
  "os" : "Windows 7",
  "os_name" : "Windows 7",
  "major" : 7
}
```

However, it's actually IE11. Following tables are taken from [M$ documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx):

**Trident token**

> When the F12 developer tools are used to change the browser mode of
>   Internet Explorer, the version token of the user-agent string is
>   modified to appear so that the browser appears to be an earlier
>   version. This is done to allow browser specific content to be served
>   to Internet Explorer and is usually necessary only when websites have
>   not been updated to reflect current versions of the browser. When this
>   happens, a Trident token is added to the user-agent string. This token
>   includes a version number that enables you to identify the version of
>   the browser, regardless of the current browser mode.

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║    Token    ║     Description      ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ Trident/7.0 ║ IE11                 ║
║ Trident/6.0 ║ Internet Explorer 10 ║
║ Trident/5.0 ║ Internet Explorer 9  ║
║ Trident/4.0 ║ Internet Explorer 8  ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

However it seems that user-agent plugin looks after MSIE X.0 to reflect major version. This is another table from documentation:

```
╔═══════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Version token ║                            Description                             ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ MSIE 10.0     ║ Internet Explorer 10                                               ║
║ MSIE 9.0      ║ Internet Explorer 9                                                ║
║ MSIE 8.0      ║ Internet Explorer 8 or IE8 Compatibility View/Browser Mode         ║
║ MSIE 7.0      ║ Windows Internet Explorer 7 or IE7 Compatibility View/Browser Mode ║
║ MSIE 6.0      ║ Microsoft Internet Explorer 6                                      ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So this means that even if it's IE11, it's going to be parsed as IE7 because of compatibility mode.

Is it possible to fix it or I'll have to change user-agent plugin regex by myself to reflect true browser version in order to store it correctly?

P.S. I'm taking records from external database.

Comment: You can change the user agent string without entering compatibility mode. Development tools 》emulation.

Comment: I don't need that. I just want correct IE version to be parsed regardless of compatibility mode. My records are already stored in external database. Edited question to reflect that.

Comment: Correct string parsed regardless of compatibility mode - that's what I described.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me. I have tons of user-agent records present in database and I'd like to import all of this into Logstash and parse them. So if there's a user-agent string like the one in my question, I'd like to get `"major": 11`, not `"major": 7`.